# Why is python giving "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.xxx'; '__main__' is not a package" when import with .?

Tags: python, python-import

I got two .py file in the same directory. I try to use .filename to import, but python raises the error.

[image]

If I delete the ., then it works fine but pycharm is giving me warning

[image]

What's the correct way to import?

Code in test_trial.py:

```
def test():
    print('hello world')
```

Code in test_trial_2.py

```
from test_trial import test

test()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what warning you're getting?

Comment: You mean for PyCharm? It writes "Unresolved reference 'test_trial' "